# Fundamental group of projective plane with handles

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I was told that the fundamental group of the projective plane with g handles is isomorphic to $\langle c_1, \ldots, c_{2g+1} | c_1^2 \cdot \ldots \cdot c_{2g+1}^2\rangle$. How can I show it?

I can think about this topological space as of factorization of a polygon. Namely, it's a polygon with $2 + 4g$ sides: $cc a_1 b_1 a_1^{-1} b_1^{-1} \ldots a_g b_g a_g^{-1} b_g^{-1}$, which are glued in a standard way. So we have a cellular decomposition with one 2-cell, so the fundamental group of the space is $\langle c, a_1, b_1, \ldots, a_g, b_g | c^2 \cdot [a_1, b_1] \cdot \ldots \cdot [a_g, b_g]\rangle$. So it remains to show that it's isomorphic to the aforementioned one.

I didn't succeed neither with cutting that polygon and gluing parts to get another word on it's boundary (like one can do with the Klein bottle to get $a^2 b^2$ from a more usual representation with $abab^{-1}$) nor with direct algebraic arguments (e.g. to find Tietze transformations from one representation to another).

Comment: Can you do it when you attach *one* handle?

Comment: @Mariano, nope. It seems that one handle case should be easily generalized.

Comment: Note that $T \# \Bbb  RP^2$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb RP^2 \# \Bbb RP^2 \# \Bbb RP^2$ (do some cutting-pasting with the fundamental polygons). Now compute $(T \# T \# \cdots \# T) \# \Bbb RP^2$ ($g$ times) by associativity of connected sums. Prove that this is the sphere with $2g+1$ cross-caps attached.

Comment: @Balarka: thanks, now I see. Actually, the core of the question was how could one show that, but I see now. It's easily seen, by cutting-gluing, that fundamental polygon $A^{-1} B cc \simeq A c_1 B c_1$, where $A, B$ are some words, $c, c_1$ are some letters. So $(a b)(a^{-1} b^{-1}) cc \simeq b^{-1} (a^{-1} c_1 a^{-1}) b^{-1} (c_1) = (a^{-1} c_1 a^{-1}) b^{-1} (c_1) b^{-1} \simeq a c_1^{-1} a c_1 b_1 b_1 = (c_1^{-1}) a (c_1 b_1 b_1) a \simeq c_1 c_1 b_1 b_1 a_1 a_1$.